# Movable Images on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, image, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I am trying to make an app on xamarin forms in C# where the user can click on an image and then click on one of seven places and the image will move to the place that was clicked on. I've tried using the TranslateTo functionality of images but that does not seem to work. I also tried using Skia Sharp to create bitmaps becuase they have an intuitive coordinate system but I don't know how to make the SKBitmaps clickable. Is there a way, using skia sharp or not, to make clickable images that can be moved according to an intuitive coordinate system?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it in SkiaSharp, but you have to handle your touch input/gestures on your SKCanvasView - translate them into touch input/gestures to your primitives within SKCanvasView, then change position of your primitives according to your logic and finally refresh your SKCanvasView.